# How to run a google Colab Notebook from terminal?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, google-colaboratory

Suppose I have a Google Colab Notebook in an address like below:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/XYZ

I want to keep it running for 12 hours, however, then again I want to turn my computer off. As a solution, I can connect to our Lab's server via ssh. The server is running all the time. I would like to know if it's possible that I load and run the notebook there?
I found a solution to connect to a Google Colab Session via ssh (`colab_ssh` package), but it again needs a running Colab Session.

I also tried to browse the link with `lynx`, but it needs login and this isn't supported by this browser.

Comment: Does the server support X11 forwarding (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely) and do you have permission to install a modern browser like firefox?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I can install Firefox on the server, then how to browse with it when I just have connected using a terminal which is in text mode? I must check X11, is it a solution to see the firefox running on the server on my local machine?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes interesting, I can see the remote firefox on my machine... yeah X11 forwarding could be an answer. How long it would keep alive? Should or can I run it in a tmux?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You would first need to download your colab notebook as an `.ipynb` file, then copy it to your server. Then, you can follow one of the guides on how to connect to a remotely running jupyter notebook session, like [this](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2018/01/31/running-a-jupyter-notebook/) one. All you need is the jupyter notebook software on your server, and an ssh client on your local computer.

Edit: I forgot to mention this: To keep your session alive even after closing the ssh connection, you can use tools like [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/). The link provides more detailed explanation, but the general idea is that after connecting to your server, first you need to create a session like this:

```
screen -S <session_name>
```

which will create a new session and *attach* you to it (which is the term used when you are inside a session). Then, you can fire up your jupyter notebook here, and it will keep running even after closing the ssh connection.  (You just have to make sure you don't kill the screen session using `Ctrl+a` followed by `k`)

Now, you have an indefinitely running jupyter notebook session on your server. You can connect to it via

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:YYYY:localhost:XXXX remoteuser@remotehost
```

as mentioned in the first linked guide, use the browser to run a code cell on your jupyter notebook, and then turn off your laptop without worrying about interrupting your notebook session.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I know how to forward jupyter running on my Lab's server to my laptop. You want to say that's possible with the google session and the remote server (Lab server)? Then, would the session keep alive even if I close my browser on laptop?

Comment: @Ahmad yes, I forgot to mention this part in my original answer. I edited my answer to include it.

Comment: So, I need to find out the jupyter running on the virtual machine of Google Colab. What you wrote is again not my question. I have no problem of closing ssh and I was familiar with `tmux`, thank you for that. My problem was closing FireFox window I opened Google colab with. I also could tunnel the VM behind this notebook, maybe I just need to find the jupyter running there...

Comment: @Ahmad well, I don't know if there is any way to keep a notebook running on **colab**   after closing the browser window. I was guiding you on how you can have your **notebook** run on a remote server you have access to (which is independent from google colab). I assumed it would help since you asked "I would like to know if it's possible that I load and run the notebook **there**?" (there being the remote server, not colab).

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway, this gave me some ideas that I must test...

Comment: @Ahmad I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: Does the colab notebook need to be running or can you initiate it?